# How to Access each chunks of res.write() in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

What i want is Whenever *python prints* the statement it should sent to the react and after python script run success, it should end the response Object.

As of [DOCUMENTATION](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) `res.write()` will send `multiple responses`. How to Access those res.write() on each chunks from `react`. I don't know if this is possible or not!. If there are any other ways of doing it please suggest some alternate answer

### Node JS

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ''));

const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell')

app.get('/run', (req, res) => {
    try {
        let pyshell = new PythonShell('main.py');

        pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
            res.write(message)
        });

        pyshell.on('stderr', function (stderr) {
            res.write("Failed", stderr)
        });

        pyshell.end(function (err, code, signal) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Some Error Occured While Running Script!", err)
            }
            console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
            console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
            console.log('finished');
            res.end()
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
    }
});

app.listen(3000, error => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
    }
    console.log('Server listening on 3000');
});
```

### React Code

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/run', {
       method: 'GET', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
   })
       .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```

Comment: It sounds like connecting the React app directly to the Python app via a socket connection would be a better approach. Please make sure this isn't an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) (asking about your potentially unsuitable solution rather than your actual problem)

Comment: What do you mean by python app? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean `main.py`, the Python script you're running on the server

Comment: My Question is get the value of res.write() in react